# How to calculate ENDISI on QGIS using the Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm a student currently trying to go about developing an ENDISI layer on Sentinel 2 Imagery I got from Earth Explorer. However QGIS does not have the 'mean' operator on its raster calculator for me to be able to develop it. Does anyone know how I can go about it without using the 'mean' operator. Below are the equations I'm planning on using in QGIS. Not sure If I should find the mean for each of the bands used (that need to be multiplied by the 'mean' operator). [Formulas](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/journal-of-applied-remote-sensing/volume-13/issue-01/016502/Enhanced-normalized-difference-index-for-impervious-surface-area-estimation-at/10.1117/1.JRS.13.016502.full) are expressed as follow:

[image]

where:

[image]

and,

[image]

Values of ρBlue, ρSWIR1, and ρSWIR2 are the surface reflectance of the blue, first shortwave-infrared, and second shortwave-infrared bands, respectively. (•)Mean is the mean image value. α is a correction factor calculated by Equation (2), which is used to stretch the value of ENDISI to −1, 1.

Comment: Mean for each considered image (ρBlue, ρSWIR1/ρSWIR2 and MNDWI) is a number so, they are constants. In QGIS, you can easily estimate them by using Information layer properties en each case. Afterward, you can perfectly calculate ENDISI by using QGIS Raster Calculator because α is also a number produced by a combination of constants.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your reply! So just to confirm, I am meant to estimate the mean for each image, then implement them into the equation for α, and afterwards calculate the ENDISI on the raster calculator. And how would I be able to estimate them (just as you said via the information layer properties)? I usually use ArcMap but my licence doesn't allow me to use the raster calculator so I'm pretty new at this :)

Comment: Load images in QGIS, double click on name's layer, select Information option and, finally, see mean value for corresponding image (don't forget to write down it).

Comment: Hi! Quick update, I tried it out and didn't get the values to match up to -1 to 1 (approx) just as they should. My values seem to be really large,  minimum value=1500, maximum value= 5000.  I tried playing with the values from the symbology tab but its turning into a solid colour (because its obvious, the minimum value of the generated image is higher than 1 ).  I know the α is meant to be a correction value that fixes this and brings the image to -1 to 1 but I dont know if it worked.

Comment: Bands of Sentinel 2 products (B1 to B12) must be scaled (multiplied by 0.0001).

Comment: Ah! thats why its probably coming up like this! I'll give it a go and see how it goes! hopefully this will work! Thank you so much for all of your help! I'll keep you updated on how it goes! thanks :)

Comment: so just to confirm should I be scaling the mean of the respective bands that im using in the calculations? or do I just multiply the bands that I'm using by 0.0001 via the raster calculator to generate new scaled rasters?

Comment: Hi! Update on the ENDISI calculation, I managed to do it and get fairly decent results! I'd like to thank you for all of your help! Its greatly appreciated :))